# Scaling a secondary y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am new to ggplotly and R and I am struggling on the simplest issue. I want to zoom in on my secondary axis so the data stand out. However simple math does not seem to be working.

Squaring and square rooting the data. Adjusting ylim

```
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
data = read_excel("./Input/VC_AV.xlsx")
data[,2:4] <- data[,2:4]/1000000
data[,5:7] <- data[,5:7]/100000
head(data)
data_clean = gather(data, "Scenario", "Value", -Time)
head(data_clean)
p <- data_clean  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, y=Value, col=Scenario)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Scenario)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scale, name = "Coastal Proximity Amenity Value (NZ$M)")) +
  labs(x="Time", y= ("Vulnerable Residential Capital(NZ$M)")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
p
ggplotly(p)
```

I wish to zoom in on the secondary y-axis to show the differences in the dataset while maintaining the original left-hand y-axis.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Num.png)

Comment: 1) Please include a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example      2) You refer to squaring and quare rooting the data but I can't see that in the code. 3) Where is `scale` defined? 4) In ggplot, secondary axes are ornament and don't change where the data appears, so I'm not sure how adding one will help the data stand out.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will take your advice as its ornamental and just adjust the ylim. Strange that it is so easy to do in excel but not ggplot.